# find().toArray() doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, mongodb, find, robo3t, toarray

I'm quite new to mongodb and I'm having some issues I cannot find answers to.

My question is performance I suppose. When I'm trying to query a collection using `db.collection.find()` I can get all the result and look through them in robomongo. What I need is getting all the objects into array. I perform `db.collection.find().toArray()` which doesn't return anything. That said `db.collection.find().limit(1000).toArray()` returns an array with 1000 elements just fine. So I made a conclusion that this is somehow related to performance. The collection I query has about 9000 elements, which is not that much.

Here are several lines from `stats()` output:

```
"count" : 9139,
"size" : 9210256,
"avgObjSize" : 1007,
"numExtents" : 6,
"storageSize" : 11182080,
"lastExtentSize" : 8388608.0,
"paddingFactor" : 1.0,
```

Using `forEach()` on cursor doesn't seem to make things better. So I wonder how would one get objects of a collection into array?

Comment: Have you tried `db.collection.find().toArray(function(err, result){console.log(result)})` ?

Comment: Same result, nothing is returned or printed.

Comment: Try adding some consoles like `console.log("test")` and see if it is coming inside the callback.

Comment: Same. I'm using `print` instead of `console.log`, can this be a reason?